# How to Auto Send crash logs to HokeyApp in Xamarin.iOS with extra information?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, hockeyapp

I am using Hockeyapp to log crashes in my Xamarin application.
For Android I used this code to auto submit crashes with little extra info:
**Inside MainActivity OnCreate method:**

`CrashManager.Register(this, "APP_ID", new CustomCrashListener());`

**CustomCrashListener:**

```
public class CustomCrashListener : CrashManagerListener
{
    public override bool ShouldAutoUploadCrashes()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override string UserID => "UserID recovered from settings.";
    public override string Contact => "More info from settings.";
    public override string Description => "Custom Description";
}
```

Now for the iOS I have found this to auto upload crashes:

**Inside AppDelegate:**

```
BITHockeyManager manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
manager.Configure("APP_ID");
manager.CrashManager.CrashManagerStatus = BITCrashManagerStatus.AutoSend;
manager.StartManager();
manager.Authenticator.AuthenticateInstallation();
```

My problem is that I can't find something similar to Android in iOS to send some extra little information with the auto send of crash logs, **is there any way to do that in iOS?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `UIApplicationDelegate` class, add the `IBITHockeyManagerDelegate` and/or `IBITCrashManagerDelegate`.

#### UIApplicationDelegate Example:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate, IBITHockeyManagerDelegate, IBITCrashManagerDelegate
```

#### Assign it to your `BITHockeyManager.Delegate`:

```
var hockeyManager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
hockeyManager.Delegate = (HockeyApp.iOS.BITHockeyManagerDelegate)(IBITHockeyManagerDelegate)this;
```

#### Implement which **extra info** methods you need:

```
// From IBITHockeyManagerDelegate
[Export("userIDForHockeyManager:componentManager:")]
public string UserIdForHockeyManager(BITHockeyManager hockeyManager, BITHockeyBaseManager componentManager)
{
    return "sushihangover";
}

[Export("userNameForHockeyManager:componentManager:")]
public string UserNameForHockeyManager(BITHockeyManager hockeyManager, BITHockeyBaseManager componentManager)
{
    return "Sushi Hangover";
}

[Export("userEmailForHockeyManager:componentManager:")]
public string UserEmailForHockeyManager(BITHockeyManager hockeyManager, BITHockeyBaseManager componentManager)
{
    return "sushihangover@hacktheplanet.me";
}

// From IBITCrashManagerDelegate
[Export("applicationLogForCrashManager:")]
public string ApplicationLogForCrashManager(BITCrashManager crashManager)
{
    return "StackOverflow rocks...";
}
```

Ref: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/hockeyapp-for-ios#crashreporting

Comment: I tried this `hockeyManager.Delegate = (HockeyApp.iOS.BITHockeyManagerDelegate)(IBITHockeyManagerDelegate)this;` but got an invalid cast exception.
Then I tried to do safe cast like this `(IBITHockeyManagerDelegate) this as HockeyApp.iOS.BITHockeyManagerDelegate;` but didn't get any information as intended.

Comment: Note: The delegates are called on the next app start, not at crash time!

Comment: @Kerni Yeah, I know this, and I am always launching my application again after the crash to check it on Hokeyapp.

Comment: I was able to make it work using your answer, but I changed one thing, instead of calling `hockeyManager.Delegate = (HockeyApp.iOS.BITHockeyManagerDelegate)(IBITHockeyManagerDelegate)this;` I added the delegate to the Configure method like this: `manager.Configure(HOCKEYAPP_APP_ID, this);`